# Nonlinear equation over integers

Tags: nonlinear-system, integers

Let $F$ be a positive rational number, and $j,\ell,k\in \mathbb{Z}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$ with $j=(j_1,j_2)$, $\ell=(\ell_1,\ell_2)$, $k=(k_1,k_2)$.

We suppose that $F$ and $k$ are fixed. How to solve this nonlinear system with respect to $(j,l)$?

$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
\dfrac{j_1}{j_1^2+j_2^2+F}+\dfrac{\ell_1}{\ell_1^2+\ell_2^2+F} & =
\dfrac{k_1}{k_1^2+k_2^2+F}, \\[8pt]
j_1+\ell_1 & =k_1, \\[8pt]
j_2+\ell_2 & =k_2.
\end{align}
\right.
$$

Comment: Is $F$ an integer, rational, real ( presumably not complex ? ) ?

Comment: F is a real number.

Comment: In this case solve the equation for $F$ and the resulting expression for the cubic roots and the requirement for a real value will place limitations on what values the other variables can take.  Outside of that I do not see how you can extract any other information as there are no other constraints.

Comment: The parameter F is arbitrary. So, if we fix F and $k$, what are the ($j$,$l$) who check the system?

Comment: I changed the statement of the problem because the case where F is irrational is resolved.